# Problems about the memory usage in Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, pyflink

I have a Flink program looks like this:

```
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
env.set_runtime_mode(RuntimeExecutionMode.STREAMING)
env.set_parallelism(1)

source1 = KafkaSource.builder() \
        .set_bootstrap_servers('kafka:9092') \
        .set_topics('HPT1') \
        .set_value_only_deserializer(SimpleStringSchema()) \
        .build()
  
ds = env.from_source(source1, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source")
ds = ds.map(lambda i : mapping_func(i)) \
       .key_by(lambda i : i[1]) \
       .reduce(lambda i, j : mean_sqrt(i, j))
ds.print()
env.execute()
```

in which the `mapping_func` is a simple function that returns a tuple, and the `mean_sqrt` is a function to calculate the mean square of the data from the datasource. Using `reduce` might not be the best solution but the results of calculation suit me well.

Never mind these details, my problem is about the memory usage of the program. I notice that, when Flink is up but with no task running, the memory occupied by *taskmanager* is about 200MB. When I submit a job(the code block above), the memory first grows to about 400MB, then slowly grows to an upper bound, like 650MB, and finally fluctuates around there.

I guess the memory usage growth is caused by allocating JVM heap memory to a task, and then some states and intermediate results are stored on the heap. but why would it reach an upper bound? I didn't use any mechanism like state TTL to clear the states.

By the way, is there a method to limit the memory usage of a Flink process? In my scenario, Flink will be deployed on IoT devices, so I'd like to limit the resource it might take, for example, limiting the memory occupied by *taskmanager* within 300MB while the job is running. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Also, I noticed that after canceling a running job, the taskmanager would still occupy a few hundred MBs memory additionally, compare to the initial status.

Comment: It also confuses me that even if the Task Heap is set to 0, the job can still run properly and the test result of a 10 minutes window remained true!!!